# To make a distance matrix or to repeatedly calculate distance

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on [K-medoids algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) implementation. It is a clustering algorithm and one of its steps includes finding the most representative point in a cluster.

So, here's the thing

- I have a certain number of clusters
- Each cluster contains a certain number of points
- I need to find the point in each cluster that results with the least error if it is picked as a cluster representative
- Distance from each point to all the other in the cluster needs to be calculated
- This distance calculation could be simple as Euclidean or more complex like DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) between two signals

There are two approaches, one is to calculate distance matrix that will save values between all the points in the dataset and the other is to calculate distances during clustering, which results that distances between some points will be calculated repeatedly.

On one hand, to build distance matrix you must calculate distances between all points in the whole dataset and some of calculated values will never be used.

On the other hand, if you don't build the distance matrix, you will repeat some calculations in certain number of iterations.

Which is the better approach?

I'm also considering MapReduce implementation, so opinions from that angle are also welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 3rd approach could be a combination of both, and is lazily evaluating the distance matrix. Initialize a matrix with default values (unrealistic values, like negative ones), and when you need to calculate distance between two points, if the values is already present in the matrix - just take it from it.
Otherwise, calculate it and store it in the matrix.

This approach trades calculations (and is optimal in doing the lowest number of possible pair calculations), for more branches in the code, and a few more instructions. However, due to branch predictors, I assume this overhead will not be that dramatic.

I predict it will have better performance when the calculation is relatively expansive.

Another optimization of it could be to dynamically switch for a plain matrix implementation (and calculate the remaining part of the matrix) when the number of already calculated exceeds a certain threshold. This can be achieved pretty nicely in OOP languages, by switching the implementation of the interface when a certain threshold is met.

Which is actually better implementation is going to rely heavily on the cost of the distance function, and the data you are clustering, as some will need to calculate the same points more often than other data sets.

I suggest doing a benchmark, and using [statistical tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) to evaluate which method is actually better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any comments on the MapReduce  implementation part?

Comment: @pera A map-reduce implementation with O(n^2) communications from a mapper is trivial, and can improve performance significantly if the distance calculation is very expansive, are you interested on it? Or is it irrelevant for your case?

Comment: Actually, I am interested. Could you elaborate more on it? I was thinking about some sort of K-means like algorithm, very you basically try out all the elements in cluster and find the element that is the most similar to all the others. But, that is O(n^2) after all, and we're talking about big data. Besides that, a lot of data needs to be written to HDFS, to allow all of that calculation,and also a lot of data needs to transfered. I'm not sure what idea do you have?

Comment: @pera Might have misuderstood you, I neant calculating the distances in map-reduce with O(n^2) communication is trivial. One mapper that generates (pi,pj) for each i,j. Then, multiple reducers, each working on different point (i for example), and calcualte d(pi,pj) for all j. This is a good distribution of the d(.,.) calculation if it's expansive, but there is still O(n^2) battle neck for the mapper, though it's relatively simple battleneck, since no distance calculations at all in it. And obviously, no combiner.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea, but you do need to create n^2 amount of data for the calculations.But I'm not sure I understand you correctly, you said - "One mapper that generates (pi,pj) for each i,j. Then, multiple reducers, each working on different point (i for example), and calculate d(pi,pj) for all j", but isn't it the opposite way?I mean, you cannot influence on the number of mappers,while you can on reducers.And it seems more reasonable to give all the input to mappers,so they could calculate d(pi,pj).Regardless of this,how would you use that matrix?It would be large,how to distribute?

Comment: @pera You cannot do it in mapper, because you need someone to read ALL points, this is the job of the mapper. The O(n^2) generated space is done by the map-reduce framework and is usually on files. The distribution is done by the framework, each reducer get a different key (point), and calculate distances from it to all other points.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong,but that means that if there milion points there would be milion reducers,where each reducer would calculate dustances to all the other points?

Comment: @pera The framework takes care for it, it can generates as many reducers as it can, and distributed the million tasks among them